# Symfony2 - kernel.exception seems not called in prod / no-debug mode

Tags: symfony

I have attached an observer on kernel.exception to print a custom error page.

In prod, with debug mode : it's OK.
In prod, with no-debug mode : it's NOK.

I have try to clear cache (--env=prod --no-debug), (--env=prod), (and delete directly files).
No result.

Like the kernel.exception event was disabled or stopped.

In container cache file (appProdProjectContainer.php) I see my observer entry :

```
$instance->addListenerService('kernel.exception', array(0 => 'ui.exception.event_listener', 1 => 'onKernelException'), 0);
[...]
$instance->addListenerService('kernel.exception', array(0 => 'twig.exception_listener', 1 => 'onKernelException'), -128);
```

Perhaps, it's a priority issue ? (-128 vs 0) ?
I have try to change it : No result.

Have you an idea, a way ?

Thanks.

Comment: on some exception like HTTPNotFoundException : It's OK.
But on other custom exception : it's NOK.
I have activated monolog : debug, and when it's NOK, the last debug message is : [2012-11-14 18:32:12] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have upgraded vendors for old symfony2 application and my app/AppKernel.php have such a code

`\Monolog\ErrorHandler::register($logger);`

After disabling that line my error listener start working.